# iOS (ObjC) PromiseKit - Return promise within promise

Tags: ios, objective-c, promise, promisekit

I'm trying to cascade a promise through some classes which add functionality at each level.

```
+ (AnyPromise *) method {
    return [SomeClass whichReturnsPromise]
    .then(^(id obj){
        // do stuff
        return obj;
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately this code is throwing an error on the second line:

**`exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x10)`**

(Note: just calling `return [SomeClass whichReturnsPromise]` works fine)

I've scoured stackoverflow answers and tried many variations of the above code (which would work in javascript), but I keep getting the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a break case for `[SomeClass which ReturnsPromise]` was returning `nil` from before it was converted to return a promise. Changed it to return a promise with value `nil`. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, I think the following should work:

```
[self wait].then(^{
   return [SomeClass whichReturnsPromise];
}).then(^(id obj) {
   return obj;
});
```

I know the following is Swift, but if you have an `AnyPromise` you can use it in a `Promise<T>` chain:

```
someSwiftPromise().then { _ -> AnyPromise in
   // provided by `pod PromiseKit/SystemConfiguration`
   return SCNetworkReachability()
}.then { (obj: AnyObject?) in
   // AnyPromise always resolves with `AnyObject?`
}
```

Comment: What class is `[self wait]` from? I'm calling mine on a custom class.

Comment: Oh, then what happens if you add a semicolon `;` to your `return [SomeClass whichReturnsPromise]`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: You mean if I take out the `.then` clause? No error.